# Nice wordpress to wordpress redirect?

Tags: wordpress, redirects, blog, plugin

I have a WordPress blog in http://suportrecerca.barcelonamedia.org/blog/ , and since I can no longer use our company servers for my blog I've had to move it to blog.joanmarcriera.es

Google had my old blog well indexed and many people is landing to my old blog. 
I want to redirect this people to my new blog in a nice way, like a 5 seconds delay with some information or something.

Any suggestions?

I also would like to let Google index the old blog like usual if it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [301 redirect](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=301+redirect). Place this in your .htaccess file of the old URL:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?suportrecerca\.barcelonamedia\.org/blog/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.joanmarcriera.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will tell Google, and browsers and other search engines, that your site has moved locations. You will see some fluctuation in your rankings while Google makes the transition from the old site to the new site but after all is said and done your new site should replace the old site in the SERPs and retain its ranking.

Comment: I tried this method, but it is not working for me at 
http://www.steve.doig.com.au/wordpress/computing.  Any suggestions?